# Avoiding downcasting, double dispatch

Tags: c++, unit-testing, oop

I did something similar to the following code:

```
void launchPipeline(IQueryFactory & queryFactory, IQuerySender &querySender, IValidateResponse &responseValidator)
{
    std::unique_ptr<IQuery> query = queryFactory.getInstance();

    /*
    auto a,b,c = querySender.send(query);
    //we just get a lot of params from that function
    */

    if(responseValidator.validate(query, a, b, c)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
class IValidateResponse
{
   public:
    virtual bool validate(IQuery & query, int a, int b, int c) = 0;
};

class QueryAValidator
{
   public:
    bool validate(IQuery & query, int a, int b, int c) override
    {
        const auto & queryA = dynamic_cast<const QueryA &>(query);
        //do something
    }
};
```

It works perfectly fine because matching types of `IQueryFactory` and `IValidateResponse` are injected in. But I was wondering if this could be avoided in some fancy way?

I was thinking about `QueryVisitor` but I'm not sure how to implement it, the visit function would require to take a, b, c params which would look weird on `IQuery` interface, like `query.accept(visitor, a, b, c)`.

Or I could store these params inside the visitor, but that still doesn't feel smooth, especially when it comes to writing tests. For now I have so called "validators tests" where I simply put fake response and test the concrete Validator class, adding visitor to that would make them more complicated.

How would you solve that?

Comment: Just curious, but `validate` isn't declare public, it's private. How does `launchPipeline` manage to invoke this method?

Comment: My bad, an oversight.

Comment: Is this just for unit test code?  If it's just for test code, then who cares? You're permitted a degree of imperfection in test code so you don't have to re-engineer all your product code's object model to avoid a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Define a pure virtual function in IQuery and call it foo(int a, int b, int c). In QueryA you override foo with the code you defined with "//do something" after the dynamic cast. Replace the dynamic cast with query.foo(a, b, c)

Comment: The thing is I want to have dedicated interface for that, which is IValidateResponse

Comment: What about defining a pure virtual function in IQuery that is called virtual IValidateResponse* getValidateResponse() = 0; With this function, Each Query can return its own ValidateResponse.

Comment: I just saw that you tagged the question with unit-test. So, do not use the QueryFactory in your test, but test each concrete type of IQuery with separate code. This means, do not use IQuery in the test, but use QueryA.